# Trigger issue on update field

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table 'TEST' with some columns. One of them is called 'VALIDATED'. This column is a bit.

```
 TEST Table:
  Id1   Id2    VALIDATED
   1        1              0
   1        2              0
   1        3              0
   2        4              0
   2        5              0
   2        6              0
```

Id1 and Id2 are INT values and primary keys.

I have created below trigger for this table and for that column 'VALIDATED' only when it is updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MY_TRIGGER]   
   ON  [dbo].[TEST] 
   FOR UPDATE 
AS 
IF UPDATE([VALIDATED])
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @VALIDATED_INSERT BIT;
    SELECT @VALIDATED_INSERT = [VALIDATED]
    FROM INSERTED;

    PRINT 'VALIDATED INSERT:'
    PRINT @VALIDATED_INSERT

    DECLARE @VALIDATED_TABLE BIT;
    SELECT @VALIDATED_TABLE = [VALIDATED]
    FROM [dbo].[TEST]

    PRINT 'VALIDATED TABLE:'
    PRINT @VALIDATED_TABLE

END
```

Imagine we update row which has Id1=1 and Id2=1 using below update statement and field 'VALIDATED' is set to 0 initially as above table TEST shows:

```
Update TEST
SET VALIDATED=1
Where Id1= 1 and Id2 = 1
```

1) If I update this column 'VALIDATED' to 1 it prints:

```
VALIDATED INSERT:
1
VALIDATED TABLE:
1
```

2) Now, VALIDATED is set to 1 in the table so If I update it again for the same row (Id1 = 1 and Id2 = 1):

```
Update TEST
SET VALIDATED=0
Where Id1= 1 and Id2 = 1
```

It prints:

```
VALIDATED INSERT:
0
VALIDATED TABLE:
1
```

I don't understand it:

- Why in case 1) VALIDATED TABLE is printed as 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Are you aware that the `inserted` (virtual) can contain more than one row? That would be the case for bulk inserts, or mass inserts... You already have a red flag in the first statement of your trigger...

Comment: @TT. Yes, I am aware. In this case inserted has only one row when trigger is fired. red flag? breakpoint? I haven't any.

Comment: Show the record in your table and the update statements you make to fire this trigger

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. You assume that inserted will only ever have a single row. That is not how triggers work in sql server, they fire once per operation not once per row. Scalar variables in a trigger being populated with either the inserted or deleted table is a clear indication the trigger is flawed.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at the base table in this case, you should be looking at deleted to retrieve the previous value and inserted for the new value.

Comment: I have updated my post to make it clearer.

Comment: To get what you are looking for, you may want to change the "For Update" to "AFTER UPDATE". Definition of After, AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks also must succeed before this trigger fires. Hence, this would imply that "FOR" would not necessarily wait until all of the operations have executed.

Comment: @SeanLange ok, so I understand previous value of table TEST is stored in DELETED and the new one in the INSERTED, right? So once trigger is fired, within trigger, TEST table has the new value which is the same as that in INSERTED table, right? Could you confirm me this, please?

Comment: I think you missed my point entirely. From a trigger you shouldn't even be trying to read the base table. Technically speaking the current value in the table is in flux because it is currently being updated. If you run a select statement from outside your transaction it will wait until your update (and the trigger) complete. If you add NOLOCK it will return the value from inserted (usually). The real point is that the value in the base table should not be considered at all.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand you. So reading value from the base table within a trigger it should not be done never since it is in flux so If I try to read the value from the base table within the trigger as in my example, then sometimes I can get 0 or sometimes 1, right?

Comment: From your trigger you may or may not get what you think the new value is. Your are effectively reading an uncommitted transaction and the results may or may not be accurate. Stick to the inserted and deleted tables and you will have accurate information every single time. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Using inserted and deleted tables is working perfectly.